# Integrating LogiXML reports in own Java EE web application

Tags: web-applications

I am evaluating LogiXML for dynamic reporting requirements in my struts/spring based web-application. do anybody  have examples or some feedback about quickly generate and deploy report in existing web-application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll likely find the best resources for finding a solution on the Logi DevNet site.

Typically, a Logi application is deployed as a fully managed web application inside a standard java application server container-- eg.  Tomcat, Jboss, Websphere, etc.   The key requirement will be to ensure that you're running JDK version 1.6+.

Here's a link to the article on configuring Java application servers for deploying Logi apps:
http://devnet.logixml.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Article&dnDocID=1179

Once your app is deployed, accessing the Logi output will be most commonly be via URL, either directly in the browser or using other types of HTML, javascript, or ajax calls (Iframes, the Logi javascript Widget, or web service requests are common)

For additional details, you may also wish to search on specific topics in the DevNet search option to scan through articles or samples.

Regards

Answer (score -1):

Check out Logi DevNet for examples http://devnet.logixml.com.

Comment: I have referred this site. but I would like to know exact information about integration process. this was kind of urgent POC work I was doing. but anyway thanks for your answer. appreciate it.